# Reuse HTTP message in different methods in Citrus Framework

Tags: java, bdd, citrus-framework

*Problem*: How to reuse the same HTTP message in two different methods (in the same step) in Citrus Framework

*Versions*: *Citrus 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT*; *Cucumber 3.0.2*; *Java 8*

Having this Gherkin:

```
    Scenario: Client has permission to access the action
        Given that client has access to action
        When the client calls the endpoint /some-endpoint/client/1/action/some-action
        Then the client receives status code of 200
        And the client receives a response with {"action" : "some-action", "permission": "AUTHORIZED"}
```

and the following piece of *Java* code:

```
  @Then("the client receives status code of {int}")
  public void the_client_receives_status_code_of(Integer statusCode) {

    designer.http().client(httpClient).receive().response(HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode))
        .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"):
  }

  @Then("the client receives a response with {string}")
  public void the_client_receives_a_response_with(String payload) {

    designer.http().client(httpClient).receive().response().payload(payload);
  }
```

If this code is run, it will give a timeout in the method `the_client_receives_a_response_with`, since *Citrus* is expecting to receive a second message (`send` method was only called once).

The objective here is to separate the validations of the *HTTP* code from the payload, so the separation was made by creating two methods. How to reuse the message received in method `the_client_receives_status_code_of`?

Already tried the following without success:

Giving a name to the received message:

```
designer.http().client(httpClient).receive().response(HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode)).name("currentMessage")
        .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

But trying to access the message like this:

```
@CitrusResource
private TestContext testContext;
...
testContext.getMessageStore().getMessage("currentMessage");
```

Returns `null`.

But using this:

```
designer.echo("citrus:message(currentMessage)");
```

Prints the correct message.

So, how can I access the message in Java code, i.e, have access to the message to do something like this:

```
Assert.assertTrue(testContext.getMessageStore().getMessage("currentMessage").getPayload().equals(payload));
```

In two different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@Then("the client receives a response with {string}")
public void the_client_receives_a_response_with(String payload) {
    designer.action(new AbstractTestAction() {
        public void doExecute(TestContext context) {
            Assert.assertTrue(context.getMessageStore()
                                         .getMessage("currentMessage")
                                         .getPayload(String.class)
                                         .equals(payload));
        }
    });
}
```

The abstract action is always provided with the current TestContext instance of your running test. So the `@CitrusResource` injection is not working here as you get a different instance where the named message is unknown.

Also as an alternative you could follow the default named messages steps BDD API that is described here: https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#named-messages

Maybe message creator BDD API will also help: https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#message-creator-steps